# How to handle if curl request throws error in magento 2

Tags: api, cron, magento2.3.1, curl-request

I am receiving a response from using a curl request. But how do I check whether my curl request throws an error or not? because it takes 15 minutes to give a response from API.(but it works fine while testing in postman)

Can anyone guide me to solve this?

```
public function getDynamicPriceFromErp($sku, $priceCode)
    {

        $url = "https://v3.test.com/v1/test/44gggttfff234";
        $this->curlClient->setOption(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $this->curlClient->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2000);
        $this->curlClient->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //set curl header
        $this->curlClient->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        $this->curlClient->addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer fhY0eXAigoY");
        //post request with url and data
        $this->curlClient->post($url);
        //read response
        $response = $this->curlClient->getBody();
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is natural behaviour of an API call. It waits for server response.
I have faced the same situation. I solved using CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT in my code. This will stop execution after 10 seconds if no response from API. Hope it help someone

`$this->curlClient->setOption(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);`